# Let all eigenvalues of $A$ have a negative real part ( i.e. $A$ is stable ). Why does the following hold?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, proof-explanation, control-theory

[image]Let all eigenvalues of $A$ have a negative real part ( i.e. $A$ is stable ). Why does the following hold?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} [Ae^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}+e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}A^*] \, d\tau = \int_0^\infty d(e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau})$$
Please may you explain the meaning of $d(e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau})$ in the right hand side of the equation.

Many thanks,

Tri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will give a partial answer without ruling out the possibility of finishing it later.

I am mildly skeptical of the equality because it seems to be neglecting a product rule that would say $\displaystyle \frac d {d\tau} \left( e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau}\right) = Ae^{A\tau}B B^* e^{A^*\tau} + e^{A\tau}BB^* A^* e^{A^*\tau}.$

But the other question is: What is the meaning of $d(e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau})$?

In the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty d(e^{A\tau}BB^*e^{A^*\tau})$ one could wonder whether the variable that goes from $0$ to $\infty$ is $\tau$ or $A$ or $B$ or something else, but that is clear from the *left* side of the equality. The only meaning one can reasonably assign to this is that that integral is the total change in $e^{A\tau} B B^* e^{A^*\tau}$ as $\tau$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty d\left(e^{A\tau} B B^* e^{A^*\tau}\right) & = \left( \lim_{\tau\to\infty} e^{A\tau} B B^* e^{A^*\tau} \right) - \left( e^{A0} B B^* e^{A^*0} \right) \\[6pt]
& = \left( \lim_{\tau\to\infty} e^{A\tau} B B^* e^{A^*\tau} \right) - \left( B B^*\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Michael. You were right I made a big mistake when copying the equation. My apologies. I have corrected this belatedly.

Comment: Regarding the first point, you might write $e^{A^*\tau}=[e^{A\tau}]^*$. So, $de^{A^*\tau}=d[e^{A\tau}]^*=[Ae^{A\tau}]^*d\tau=e^{A^*\tau}A^*d\tau$. This seems to agree with the expression in the question.